# GCP External Static IP Address can be recovered once you released it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, static-ip-address

Hello i want to know if there is a way to recover a released static IP address in GCP. I know if i release a static external IP Address it goes to a public pool of IPs and can be used by any user of GCP compute engine, teh thing is can i recover that IP address after i release it?

Comment: This probably isn't the best place to ask this question, you'd likely be better on a forum specific to GCP, stackoverflow is more for "The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."

Answer (score 2):

There is no method to recover a specific external public IP address after you release it.

You could try to assign an IP address. If you get the same one it is just pure luck.